# Converse of a theorem: If the curl of a vector field is not zero does it implies it is not conservative?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the following theorem:

If $F$ is a vector field defined in a simply-connected open set, whose coordinate functions have continuous partial derivatives and $curl(F)=0$, then $F$ is conservative.

I'm asking if the converse also holds or which additional hipotesis would make it hold.

Thanks

Comment: You need "simply connected," not just "connected" for the statement you give.  For the converse, you only need "connected."

Comment: The theorem you wrote is false. For a counterexample, use the vector field $\langle-y,x\rangle$ on the punctured plane $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0\}$.

Comment: @Paul thanks for clarifying. Lee I appologized, I've fixed it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a field $F$ defined on some open region $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}$ has vanishing curl then it is *locally* conservative, meaning that any point $p\in\Omega$ has a neighborhood $U$ such that there is a local ptential $f:\>U\to{\mathbb R}$ with $\nabla f=F$ on $U$. If $\Omega$ happens to be simply connected then these local potentials can be "concatenated" to a global potential $f:\>\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$.

Now to your question: Does ${\rm curl}\,F(p)\ne0$ imply that $F$ is not conservative in the neighborhood of $p$? The answer is **Yes**. This can be seen as follows: If there were some function $f: \>U\to{\mathbb R}$ satisfying $\nabla f=F$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ then the equality of mixed second partials of $f$ would enforce ${\rm curl}\,F(p)=0$.